# Flag Class in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a class in Java with one boolean variable named flag, that I can access and change using getter and setter in any other class.
My class code looks like this:

```
public abstract class WindowFlag {
    private boolean flag = false;

    public boolean getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```

However when I try to call `WindowFlag.setFlag(true);` I get an error:

> Cannot make a static reference to a non-static method setFlag().

However if I set the method to `static` I cannot use the value of `flag` `boolean` from this class.

How should I solve this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Is it correct that you are trying to create a global singleton to hold a boolean state? What about concurrency?

Comment: Call `setFlag()` on an instance?

Comment: Why is this class `abstract`?

Comment: the `flag` variable must be static as well as the getter and setter. However, making this flag globally accessible might not be what you want. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this design?

Comment: @forgivenson It would be better to work with `WindowFlag` instances instead of making everything static.

Comment: @arshajii Yes. I was simply informing the OP why that error was occurring. I added to my comment already

Comment: If your intention in making the class `abstract` is to prevent the creation of instances, that can be more clearly done by making the constructor `private`. But then you'd need to follow the other suggestions about making things `static`.

Comment: Did you consider [AtomicBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) - much better than rolling your own.

Answer (score 4):

Since this methods aren't static, you have to instantiate this class first:

```
WindowFlag f = new WindowFlag();
f.setFlag(true);
```

(of course, your class is abstract, so you need to provide implementation first, or remove `abstract` keyword).

Comment: I love it when I get a downvote with no explanation why.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make an instance of `WindowFlag` class.

```
WindowFlag wf = new WindowFlag(){};
```

Then call

```
wf.setFlag(true);
```

Since the class is abstract, you have to provide an implementation first. If there are no other `abstract` methods, you simply can remove the `abstract` part.

If there are other abstract methods,

```
WindowFlag w=new WindowFlag() {
// implementations of abstract methods.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You've 2 problems.  First, the class is abstract.  Remove the `abstract` keyword from the class definition as you have no need for abstraction here.

Next, create an instance of `WindowFlag` class to access a method which is not static.

```
WindowFlag flag = new WindowFlag();
flag.setFlag(true);
```

Alternatively, mark `setFlag` method as static, and your internal `flag` boolean as static.  I'd need more information about your problem to advise whether to use a static method or not, but in my experience, marking your method and variable as static is usually not the way to go.

Comment: I would like to use static, because it makes more sence to me, since I can access it trough any time from any class easier. I just need this one flag value to be available any time anywhere, so I think it makes more sense to use abstract. I just have one problem: when I make my setFlag() method static I get an error that this cannot be used in static context.

Comment: Marking it abstract won't allow you to use it from anywhere.  Marking it static will though.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

#### Instantiate a WindowFlag

```
class MyClass {
    static WindowFlag flag;
    static {
        flag = new WindowFlag() {};
        // This {} is needed for creating an anonymous class to
        // instantiate your abstract class
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Now you can use flag.setFlag();
    }
```

#### Make flag parameter static

Change your class:

```
public class WindowFlag {
    private static boolean flag = false;

    public static boolean getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public static void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```

```
{
    WindowFlag.setFlag(true);
}
```

As [William Morrison pointed out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25328566/3622940), you ought not to make your class `abstract` as it doesn't have unimplemented methods.

Answer (score -1):

You will (probably) also want to make such a class thread-safe.  Try:

```
public abstract class WindowFlag {
    private static boolean flag;

    public static synchronized boolean getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public static synchronized void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```